# Function should get called only once

Tags: c#

I have one c# function which returns me List of States. I want this function should get called only once like static variable.

```
    public List GetStateList()
    {
       List lstState=new List();
       lstState.add("State1");
       lstState.add("State2");
       lstState.add("State3");

       return lstState;
    }
```

I m calling this function from many places since this state list is going to be same so i want this function should get called only once, and next time when this function is getting called it should not re create the whole list again.

How could i achieve this in c#.

Comment: return the same(static?) list in each call.

Comment: Please upload your code here.............

Comment: This question appears to betray a serious misunderstanding of what `static` means, or what the intended outcome really is. We really need a lot more information about what you really want.

Comment: Do you really want to avoid a second call to the function or you just want to avoid the (probably) expensive rebuild of your List of States?

Comment: We have no context without some code!  Are you wanting to 'cache' the list of states so to avoid fetching from the database each time?

Comment: -1 You may as well of said "make stuff work, static......"

Comment: `static bool called = false; if(!called) { UpdateList(); called = true; }`. There you go.

Comment: @Aesthete : i know this solution, i want some thing different.

Comment: The easy solution would be to check to see if `lstState` is empty.  Of course you would have to fix your overal design flaw to do this

Comment: You really aren't making it clear exactly what you want.  Every time you call the UpdateList method you are creating a new List.  I think you really need to understand exactly what you want to achieve or at least explain what you want better.  If you don't want the UpdateList method called more than once why are you calling it multiple times.  Seems a little odd.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Memoise it. It'll still be called multiple times, but only do the full work once:

```
private List<string> _states; //if GetStateList() doesn't depend on object
                              //state, then this can be static.
public List GetStateList()
{
   if(_states == null)
   {
     List lstState=new List();
     lstState.add("State1");
     lstState.add("State2");
     lstState.add("State3");
     _states = lstState;
   }
   return _states;
}
```

Depending on threading issues, you may wish to either:

1. Lock on the whole thing. Guaranteed single execution.
2. Lock on the assignment to `_states`. There may be some needless work in the early period, but all callers will receive the same object.
3. Allow for early callers to overwrite each other.

While the last may seem the most wasteful, it can be the best in the long run, as after the initial period where different calls may needlessly overwrite each other, it becomes a simpler and faster from that point on. It really depends on just how much work is done, and how often it may be concurrently called prior to `_states` being assigned to.

Comment: You can use double-checked locking, or, more simply, you can forego the bother of lazy instantiation and just create the list upfront. There's not enough overhead in memory or CPU in the creation of a list of states to warrant the effort.

Answer (score 1):

One issue with reusing a list is that callers can modify this list, which will affect any pre-existing references to it. For such a small amount of data, this isn't likely to save you very much in the long run. I'd probably be content to just return a new array each time.

I certainly wouldn't bother with lazy instantiation; populate it in the constructor and be done:

```
public static class States {
    static States() {
        All = Array.AsReadOnly(new string[] { "state1", "state2", "state3" });
    }
    public static readonly ReadOnlyCollection<string> All;
}
```

Now it's thread-safe, (relatively) tamper-proof, and above all, simple.